# Moving a polygon to specific coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3

I have downloaded a polygon online that represents the border of a property that I would like to do further work with.  The problem is that the polygon is in the incorrect place and is the incorrect size.  I've had a number of goes at moving it by exporting to a new CRS but haven't had any luck getting it to a different spot with this method.  In light of this, I was hoping to move the polygon manually from its current location to a new set of coordinates, preserving its shape in the process.  I would then have to enlarge it to fit the size of the property.

Is this possible?  Is there an easier method? If it is possible, how could I go about doing so?  I am currently using QGIS 3.16.11.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To edit a feature manually while preserving its shape:

- make sure you have the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar enabled:
   `View -> Toolbars -> Advanced Digitizing`
- Toggle edit mode for the layer
- Use these buttons to `1: Move Feature`
  `2: Rotate Feature`
  `3: Scale Feature`

[image]

Clicking a vertex on your feature will allow you to snap it to a feature in another layer, which could be useful if you know the coordinates of a particular corner, for example:

[image]

Comment: Extra love for the nice GIF.

Comment: Appreciated. If a picture speaks a thousand words then how many does a GIF speak? ;-)

Comment: Fantastic, that worked perfectly!  Thank you so much :)

Comment: wow know you is exist this as geospatial function like st_buffer or st_intersects  ?

Comment: Have you seen [st_translate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable Toggle editing of your polygon layer,
2. Select vertex tool from digitizing toolbar,
3. Bring your cursor over the polygon layer and right click on the mouse, and
4. You will see a table of the x and y coordinates of your polygon layer, under the layer window.

Now, you can edit all the x and y coordinates from the table.